# Dealing with homographs when counting n-grams in scikit-learn

Tags: nlp, scikit-learn, tf-idf, lemmatization

I'm using TfIdfVectorizer to count n-grams in the text, but I need to lemmatize it first. One written form can correspond to different lemmas, so all of them should be counted. How can I deal with it within scikit-learn context? Do I need to write an analyser and pass it to TfIdfVectorizer? How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

See the [development version's documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#customizing-the-vectorizer-classes) for example code that plugs a lemmatizer into a `CountVectorizer`; `TfidfVectorizer` usage is similar.

(Full disclosure: the example was written by yours truly.)

Comment: The WordNetLemmatizer returns only signle lemma per token. My wrapper of lemmatizer can return arbitrary number of lemmas per token, and they can't be just concatenated because the n-grams would be corrupted. That's the problem.

Comment: @lizarisk: then you might want to look into `DictVectorizer` instead and do your own feature extraction.